# Vue PWA workboxOptions exclude folder structure

Tags: vue.js, webpack, workbox, vue-pwa

I have the following vue.config.js (showing just the relevant part)

```
pwa: {
    workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
    workboxOptions: {
      swSrc: 'src/plugins/service-worker/service-worker.js',
      exclude: [/.*images\/(?!cached).*/g, /\.map$/, /manifest\.json$/]
    }
  },
```

I'm looking to exclude all `./src/assets/images/*` images unless they are in the following directory:

`./src/assets/images/cached/*`

Here is an example of this regex working: https://regex101.com/r/vANnrn/1/

However webpack/workbox still includes all of my images that might be included in components in the precache-manifest file.

My suspicion is that the `exclude` option applies to the folder structure of assets inside `/dist` rather than `/src`? If that's the case this won't work because webpack puts all images into a flat `/dist/img` folder.

Comment: Are the `.map` and `manifest.json` files being excluded? If so, maybe `/images\/(?!cached)/` solves the issue?

Comment: yes they are, but they are based on filename or extension so their final compiled file path doesn't matter